# Syntax highlighting within #+begin_src block in emacs orgmode not working

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, org-mode

I have tried many different languages and copied various examples, but none of my code blocks within orgmode get syntax highlighting. Here is what I'm trying:

```
#+begin_src python

def main():
  print "Hello %s" % ("what's the problem")

#+end_src

#+begin_src c++

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
{
  cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

#+end_src
```

When exported to HTML, it shows up in a source code block, but with no highlighting there either.

I am using the newest org (7.8.10). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Do you have this?

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

Comment: That was it, thanks.

as far as HTML exporting, I added htmlize.el ([get it here](http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el.cgi)) to get colorizing in the CSS rules when exported from org-mode.

Comment: I believe that in newer version of Emacs you can also use `M-x htmlfontify-buffer` instead of htmlize.el

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem where despite adding htmlize.el, I couldn't get the code syntax highlighting when exporting to html. I then found this very useful post and just followed the steps:

[Syntax highlighting R code in WordPress using Emacs](http://vzemlys.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/syntax-highlighting-r-code-in-wordpress-using-emacs/)

Just to reiterate the steps:

1. I copied the htmlize.el in ~/.emacs.d/ directory
2. In org mode, typed M-x byte-compile-file and navigate to the directory where the htmlize.el is located, select it and press enter. This will compile the htmlize.el file.
3. Restart emacs and export a file with code block in it. The exported html file will now have syntax highlighted code.